# Having trouble with displaying a different image preview

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, so the way I have my section set up right now is I have an image in a container. When that image is clicked, a modal pops up with a preview of that same image, and a  smaller preview of that same image underneath it along with another preview image next to that one. I am trying to have each one of the smaller preview images underneath the larger preview image act as buttons, to change the larger preview image above it depending on which image is clicked. I hope I am explaining this clearly, but let me know if not. I also am not sure if I am setting this up right at all. These are the two smaller preview images underneath the larger preview image.

```
<a type="button" data-toggle="" data-target=""></a><img class="lighthouseImg col-sm-3 col-xs-6" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/DJI_0019-Recovered.jpg'/>
 <a type="button" data-toggle="" data-target=""></a><img class="preview1 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/DJI_0073-Recovered-1.jpg'/>
```

and this is my main preview image above it that I would like to be interchangeable depending on the smaller image clicked below it

```
<div class="col-sm-6 modal3ImgPrev">
      <img class="img-responsiveModal" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/DJI_0019-Recovered.jpg'/>
</div>
```

Here is my whole section of code, along with some css.

```css
.mDialogPhoto {
  width: 95%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 0px;
}

.modal-backdrop.in {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: white;
}

.img-responsiveModal {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.modal-dialog {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section class="contentThree">
  <div class="container-fluid custom">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <h2 class="text-center photographyTitle">Shop</h2>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog mDialogPhoto" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 modal3ImgPrev">
                    <img class="img-responsiveModal" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/DJI_0019-Recovered.jpg' />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <a type="button" data-toggle="" data-target=""></a><img class="lighthouseImg col-sm-3 col-xs-6" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/DJI_0019-Recovered.jpg' />
                  <a type="button" data-toggle="" data-target=""></a><img class="preview1 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/DJI_0073-Recovered-1.jpg' />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-0 col-md-4 photoBG">
          <a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/DJI_0019-Recovered.jpg' /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <a class="btn defaultBtn btn-block" href="/videography#photography">View More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an anchor data-toggle to change the images? I'm not 100% familiar with everything you can do with bootstrap data-toggle but it doesn't seem suited for this. I recommend using a <button> tag and using an onclick event to update the image being viewed.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: You have 2 divs of row. The first being the image viewed and the second a list of image buttons. The anchor tags you have in the second row now aren't doing anything. I'd replace those anchor tags with <button> with onclick events that update the <img>; tag.

Comment: I see what your saying, but still not sure how to update the image with onclick events that update the image. I'm not too experienced with html and css.

Comment: I suggest reading up on onclick events and how to trigger a function:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Once you figure out how to call a function, then you need to set the function up to change the content of an HTML tag. This requires knowledge of how to access DOM elements:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp